# Cumulative histogram with percentage on the Y axis

Tags: r, plot, histogram, percentage

I wish to plot in R project a cumulative histogram where on the Y axes is reported the percentage instead of the frequency

```
x <- c(rnorm(100), rnorm(50, mean=2,sd=.5))
h <- hist(x, plot=FALSE, breaks=20)
h$counts     <- cumsum(h$counts)
h$density    <- cumsum(h$density)
plot(h, freq=TRUE, main="(Cumulative) histogram of x", col="white", border="black")
box()
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Set `freq=FALSE` in `hist(data, freq=FALSE)` for you to get probabilities "percentage" instead of frequencies

Comment: is it possible to add/change the bar with a line?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Isn't this a plot of the empirical cumulative distribution function? As in

```
plot(ecdf(x))
```

which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For a column plot histogram, you will want to do:

```
x <- c(rnorm(100), rnorm(50, mean=2,sd=.5))
hist( x,plot=FALSE) -> h # do a histogram of y and assign its info to h
h$counts <- cumsum(h$counts)/sum(h$counts) # replace the cell freq.s by cumulative freq.s
plot( h ) # plot a cumulative histogram of y
```

Source: http://influentialpoints.com/Training/basic_statistics_cumulative_plot.htm

Answer (score 2):

Also try:

`plot( sort(x), (1:length(x))/length(x), type="l" )`

Answer (score 1):

For a neat method Try:

```
plot.ecdf(x)
```